# Trying to make a loop for console window size

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a loop that will print a message if the window size is too small while waiting for the user to press enter. Once the user presses enter, I want it to check again if the console window is big enough before it exits the loop

```
{
    WriteLine("The current terminal size is to small to show the race track.");
    WriteLine("Please resize the window to atleast 64 character wide and 12 lines high.");
    WriteLine("Please press [enter] to continue");
    ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: What is your problem ? What is the output ? Why do you need help ?

Comment: I'm working on a project, I'm trying to make a basic console race game

Comment: "Once the user presses enter" - where in the code you've shown do you believe you're waiting for the user to press enter? "I want it to check again if the console window is big enough" - where in the code you've shown us do you believe you're finding the current size of the console window?

Comment: `width > trackWidth` looks backwards. Also needs a `Console.ReadLine()` and code to update `width` and `height` afterwards.

Comment: Since the values checked in the loop condition never change, your loop will only ever execute zero or infinite times.

Comment: but now whenever I press enter even if the window is big enough for the userInput it still repeats

Answer (score 0):

Check for a specific window size: `if (Console.WindowWidth < 120 || Console.WindowHeight < 30) {}`

In case you want the program to change it for you: `Console.SetWindowSize(120, 30);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more fully fleshsed out version...

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static int minWidth = 120;
        static int minHeight = 12;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (WindowIsTooSmall())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Make it bigger, then press enter");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        static bool WindowIsTooSmall()
        {
            return (Console.WindowWidth < minWidth || Console.WindowWidth < minHeight);
        }
    }
}
```

Make your message and variables what you want them to be to suit your needs. Put the variables at the right application level (global, whatever).

Hopefully this helps